# KSH shell script zip command not working correctly: eval: zip: cannot execute [Exec format error]

Tags: linux, zip

First off, our development environment just got upgraded to RHEL 7.5 (Maipo), we were previously on Oracle Solaris 10. Once we switched from Solaris to Red Hat this problem began. The Korn shell script below works correctly in production which is still on Solaris 10. So I am assuming that has something to do with the issue. The zip files that are being zipped up and downloaded are not saving to the zip folder. When I open the zip folder on the desktop that I just downloaded the zip folder is empty.

The pic below shows the file list. The user will select a checkbox for the files they want to download and then they click the zip and download link and it should zip up those selected files and save it to your desktop. Unfortunately the zip folder is empty. Any ideas what the problem may be?

[image]

**Here is the shell script that is being called below:**

```
 1  #!/bin/ksh
 2  #
 3  # Utility to zip up files in the configuration_aerodynamic_properties area.
 4  # Script takes two arguments the directory and the file list.
 5  # The file list is tab seperated.
 6  # This script returns the zip file.
 7  #
 8  # $Log: vmdb_zip_files.sh,v $
 9  # Revision 1.4  2014/10/21 19:53:31  wmorris1
10  # ASR 13563 - Change incorrect mime type text/text to text/plain.
11  #
12  # Revision 1.3  2012/04/30 18:46:03  wmorris1
13  # ASR 12774 - Fix SSL and IE issue found after going to SSL.
14  #
15  # Revision 1.2  2004/11/11 12:49:33  bmorris
16  # ASR 55414 - removed UNIX groups for zipped file.
17  #
18  # Revision 1.1  2004/10/18 20:10:32  bmorris
19  # Initial revision
20  #
21  #set -x
22  #set -v
23  function error_message {
24    echo "Content-Type: text/plain;"
25    echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"download_error.txt\";"
26    COMMAND="unix2dos "
27    echo ""
28    echo "$(${COMMAND}  <<-EOF
29  Error: $1
30
31  EOF
32  )"
33  }
34  if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
35    error_message "Insufficient arguments to $(basename $0)!"
36    return 1
37  fi
38  CONTENT="application/x-zip-compressed"
39  # Parse the directory path.
40  # Internal Field Sep (IFS) empty, cause spaces in file names, directories are important
41  IFS=$""
42  FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH=$(echo "${1}" | tr -d '~\\')
43  # File lists are seperated by tabs, parse them
52  IFS=$(printf '\t')
53  set -A FILE_LIST ${2}
54  # Make each of the file parameters in the file list protected.
55  let count=0
56  while (( $count < ${#FILE_LIST[*]} )); do
57    FILE_LIST[count]="\"${FILE_LIST[count]}\""
58     let count="count +1"
59  done
60  # Reset the IFS to the default.
61  IFS=$(echo " \n\t")
62  if [[ -n $3 ]]; then
63    WEB_FILENAME="$3"
64  fi
65  # Don't let the user download stuff.
66  if [[ "${1}" = *..* ]] || [[ "${1}" = *~* ]] || [[ "${2}" = *..* ]] || [[ "${2}" = *~* ]]; then
67    error_message "Path ${1}/${2} violates security."
68    return 1
69  elif [[ ! -f ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]] && [[ ! -d ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]]; then
70    error_message "${FULL_FILE_PATH} does not exist or is not regular."
71    return 1
72  elif [[ ! -r ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]]; then
73    error_message "${FULL_FILE_PATH} is not readable from the web."
74    return 1
75  fi
76  # Zip up the f
79  COMMAND="cd \"${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH}\"; zip -rX - ${FILE_LIST[*]}"
82  echo "Content-Type: ${CONTENT};"
83  if [[ -z  $HTTP_USER_AGENT || $HTTP_USER_AGENT != *MSIE* ]]; then
84    # IE Can't handle ssl and zip files
85    echo "Pragma:no-cache"
86  fi
87
88  echo ""
98  eval "$COMMAND"
```

**I debugged with set -x and here is the error log from the server:**

```
 cat vmdb_zip_files_8862.err
 + [ 3 -lt 2 ]
 + CONTENT=application/x-zip-compressed
 + IFS=''
 + tr -d '~\\'
 + echo /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
 + FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH=/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
 + printf '\t'
 + IFS=$'\t'
 + set -A FILE_LIST flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt flight_dependent_data_443949.txt
 + let count=0
 + (( 0 < 2 ))
 + FILE_LIST[0]='"flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt"'
 + let count='count +1'
 + (( 1 < 2 ))
 + FILE_LIST[1]='"flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
 + let count='count +1'
 + (( 2 < 2 ))
 + echo ' \n\t'
 + IFS=' \n\t'
 + [[ -n power_export.zip ]]
 + WEB_FILENAME=power_export.zip
 + [[ /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export == *..* ]]
 + [[ /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export == *~* ]]
 + [[ $'flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt\tflight_dependent_data_443949.txt' == *..* ]]
 + [[ $'flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt\tflight_dependent_data_443949.txt' == *~* ]]
 + [[ ! -f /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
 + [[ ! -d /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
 + [[ ! -r /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
 + COMMAND='cd "/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export"; zip -rX - "flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt" "flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
 + echo 'Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed;'
 + [[ -z 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' ]]
 + [[ 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' != *MSIE* ]]
 + echo Pragma:no-cache
 + echo ''
 + eval 'cd "/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export"; zip -rX - "flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt" "flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
 + cd /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
 + zip -rX - flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt flight_dependent_data_443949.txt
 eval: zip: cannot execute [Exec format error]
```

Not sure if zip was installed via a package or compiled manually, I will have to ask sys ops but here is the output of file `/usr/bin/zip` this gives me `/usr/bin/zip: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=747369bd1c41c4f8671a38f0055533a0c19a7769, stripped`. As for the command `uname -m` gives me this result: `x86_64`

The output for type `zip` is `zip is a tracked alias for /oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/zip` and the output for `file $(which zip)` is the following `/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/zip: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped`.

The output of `echo $PATH` is the following: `/isdev/isapps/vmdb/tools/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/isdev/isapps/vmdb/tools/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin:/isdev/isapps/vmdb/runlib/current:/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin:/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/OPatch:/tools/ileaf.ileaf/sun4os5/lib:/tools/ghostscript/current/bin/:/tools/hp2xx/bin/:/usr/lib/lp/postscript/:/tools/ileaf.ileaf/bin/::/tools/gmake/3_79_1/bin:/tools/rcs/current/bin/:/bin:/usr/j2se/bin/:/tools/gcc/3_0_3/bin:/isdev/isapps/vmdb/tools/bin:/homedev/isdev2/cmarti35/tools/java/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/contrib/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/dt/bin:/etc:/usr/etc:/opt/SUNWmotif/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/SC3.0/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin:/tools/openssh/3.7.1p2/bin/:.:/usr/bin/X11`

Comment: the script (and thus `zip`) is executing on a RH Linux host? Was zip installed via a package or compiled manually? (It has the appearance of a wrong-architecture binary). The output of `file /usr/bin/zip` and `uname -m` would help.

Comment: What is the output of `type zip`? and `file $(which zip)`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Not sure if zip was installed via a package or compiled manually, I will have to ask sys ops but here is the output of `file /usr/bin/zip` this gives me `/usr/bin/zip: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=747369bd1c41c4f8671a38f0055533a0c19a7769, stripped`. As for the command `uname -m` gives me this result: `x86_64`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The output for `type zip` is `zip is a tracked alias for /oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/zip` and the output for `file $(which zip)` is the following `/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/zip: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped`. What does this mean ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I added to output of `echo $PATH` to the question above. Do you see anything unusual?

Comment: I have added to my answer, but also note that having `.` in your `$PATH`, is dangerous, and at best a nuisance. (in your case if you create an executable script `xeyes` in the current directory, then it will run in preference to the system version. And if you have a script called `test`, it will not run.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `type zip` is telling you that it will not run `/usr/bin/zip`, therefore the output of `file /usr/bin/zip` is irrelevant. It is using the one in `/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/`, this is suspicious.

If you use `/usr/bin/zip` in your script in place of `zip`, it will fix it.

However for the long term, the problem is that your `$PATH` variable, has lots of site specific stuff that takes priority (it tries the first directory first, reading left to right). Some of this site specific stuff is miss-configured. See your site admin.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use the `/usr/bin/zip` instead of the other path? I want test and use that PATH instead to see if this will fix the issue.

Comment: @ChrisM yes see the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: I used /usr/bin/zip in my script in place of the zip command and that fixed it. I will speak to the site admin about this issue, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in ksh93 that causes this error when there is absolutely nothing wrong with the executable file.
Solaris 10 uses such archaic binaries that the Korn Shell is ksh88 (yes, 1988) which does not have this bug. Solaris 11 has ksh93 and does have this bug.  RHEL of course uses ksh93 thus has the bug but ISTR they have a fix for RHEL7, Solaris 11 doesn't have a fix.